# Understanding fgets() function

Tags: c, string, fgets

I try to write a c program to prompt user to enter a string using `fgets()` function.

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLEN 10

int main (void){
   char buffer[MAXLEN]; 
   puts("Enter text a line at a time;enter a blank to exit.");

   while(fgets(buffer,MAXLEN,stdin) != NULL){
      printf("%s",buffer);
      if(buffer[0]=='\n')
        break;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

My question is why the program still run and don't cause any undefined behaviour? since
the `MAXLEN=10` and when I entered a string with more than 10 character long the compiler don't tell anything and continues to print all the string.

Comment: The compiler never tells anything during runtime.

Comment: `fgets()` will get up to 9`char` and leave the rest in `stdin` for the next call.

Comment: @barakmanos I mean during run time,I have edited my question

@chux I have made a second call to `fgets()' and still the program run
correctly and there is no sign that the remaining strings are left over the stdin buffer.

Answer (score 3):

> and don't cause any undefined behaviour?

For one, "undefined behavior" does not mean a crash. It means that the Standard doesn't guarantee you *anything.* Now whether that is apparent or spectacular (i. e. results in a crash or something), is merely a question of luck.

> I entered a string with more than 10 character long the compiler don't tell anything and continues to print all the string.

The compiler doesn't print the string, your program does. Nor does the compiler know anything about the length of the string the user will enter.

However, you pass `fgets()` the size of the buffer (as its second parameter). **Why do you think, frankly, that parameter is there?** It's there exactly for this purpose. `fgets()` won't read more characters (at once) than it is allowed to. If that's the buffer size (which it normally should be), you will always be safe.

But I'm sure you could have deduced this yourself if you had made the effort to read `fgets()`'s documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code by adding a newline to the printing:

```
printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

This will allow you to see more exactly how `fgets()` is behaving (and it is behaving perfectly well, as it is supposed to behave).

Now go and enter a short line; you will see it printed double-spaced (with an extra newline).

Now go and enter a long line.  You will see the first 9 characters printed, then the second 9, and so on until the last few characters on the line are printed double-spaced.

Note that if you enter a line that is a multiple of 9 characters plus the newline, the loop will terminate because `fgets()` will end up returning just the newline, which your code treats as a blank line.